# HTML Image Sizing and Variables

Tags: html, image, variables, resize, dashboard

I'm using an application called iDashboards, and in it there is a feature I can add called a ViFrame that takes very limited HTML to create a custom frame.

My knowledge of HTML is already pretty limited and with no output feedback, it's hard to use trial and error as a tactic.

I'm trying to display an image. The image changes dependent on the person that's selected in the app. The selection is taken care of by itself, but the problem is that the size of the pictures vary. I'm trying to display the image so that it has a definite height and a scaled width.

Displays the full size image. The HEIGHT element doesn't seem to constrain anything. If I add a WIDTH tag it works but the scaling would be messed up. Is there any way to do what I want?

The way I see it, I have two options I can think of:
1. Make every image in the library a square and then specify square dimensions so no distortion
2. Somehow retrieve the original height and width into variables in HTML and specify both tags with height being constant and width being an expression of the ratio between height and width. None of which I know is even possible. Is it? I don't think it allows  tags either to go into JavaScript.

Sorry about my very basic knowledge in HTML, be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one object and changing the image or using many images and changing which one is displayed? Any way you could try to use `width:YOUR_VALUE_HERE; height:auto` in your css document, which should keep them all in the same ratio.

Comment: It doesn't give me a CSS document. The image changing is taken care of by the app by matching up the X axes of data. When you see the Macros line "IMG SRC="${content}/SamplePeople/${value:Image}" HEIGHT="75">" inside the HTML that's because the app is going through every refresh and matching up the currently selected row and taking the value from "Image" to complete the pathway.

Comment: can you paste the code you are using to display the image?

Comment: <TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="36" COLOR="#FFE5A1" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"><B>Employee</B></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="36" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="2" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"><IMG SRC="${content}/SamplePeople/${value:Image}" HEIGHT="75"> </FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>  This works right now.

Comment: try: `<IMG SRC="${content}/SamplePeople/${value:Image}" HEIGHT="auto" WIDTH="100px"> `

Comment: When I use that it takes away the HEIGHT component and sets WIDTH at "100" which just gives me the full size picture again. Same when it's switched.

Comment: Ok.. I am confused do you want to display all of your pictures in the same dimensions or in different? Because I thought you wanted to display your pictures in different dimensions so they wouldn't be distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Set a particular class on the IMG tag:

```
<img class='constrained_img' src='/path/to/img.png'>
```

In your CSS/Stylesheet:

```
.constrained_img {
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:100px;
 }
```

That should keep your height and width to no larger than 100px in this case.  Any further work you'd need to do server-side processing (a la PHP's getimagesize()), or use a 3rd-party library (I've used Joseph Lencioni's SLIR to good effect), or muck around with JavaScript (which isn't impossible, but off the top of my head I'm not sure how I'd go about it).

Comment: It doesn't give me a CSS/Stylesheet. I only have a GUI where I can manually type in text that converts to HTML in another tab. It's very basic.

Comment: Hmm.  If you can do HTML, you can put your stylesheet inline, might help.  <style type='text/css'>.constrained_img { blah; blah; } </style>

Comment: No luck. :/ This panel seems to limit a lot.

Comment: So, you put a stylesheet declaration into your HTML and the application removed it?